# Token-based authentication for Rails API using Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, http-headers, mongoid

I have tried to follow Ryan Bates' Railscast on [Securing an API](http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api?view=asciicast) to get the token-based authentication to run. However, the only difference is that I am using Mongoid/MongoDB instead of ActiveRecord.

I am left with the following error if I run this curl command:

```
C:\>\curl http://api.localhost:3000/books -IH 'Authorization: Token token="56d1ec82764bfcd0efa15cc44f86a757b758c4a2f39c89303c4eb0b3b1b9e229"'
```

Returned is the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
WWW-Authenticate: Token realm="Application"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Request-Id: ef24972e-766d-4014-81ea-cd13cfe2acbb
X-Runtime: 0.008001
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2014-05-08)
Date: Fri, 01 Aug 2014 09:56:57 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Set-Cookie: request_method=HEAD; path=/

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Token
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: token=56d1ec82764bfcd0efa15cc44f86a757b758c4a2f39c89303c4eb0b3b1b9e229'
```

**books_controller.rb**

```
module API    
class BooksController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_book, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :restrict_access

    def index
      @books = Book.all
      render json: @books, status: 200
    end

    private
      # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
      def set_book
        @book = Book.find(params[:id])
      end

      # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
      def book_params
        params[:book]
      end

      def restrict_access
        authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
          APIKey.where(access_token: token).exists?
        end
      end    

end
end
```

**api_key.rb**

```
class APIKey      
include Mongoid::Document      
before_create :generate_access_token

field :access_token, type: String

private
  def generate_access_token
    self.access_token = Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(Time.now.to_s)      
  end
end
```

**Rails console**

> -- APIKey.first
>
> -> #APIKey _id: 53db4baa736f6f3c3c000000, access_token: "56d1ec82764bfcd0efa15cc44f86a757b758c4a2f39c89303c4eb0b3b1b9e229"

**How can I make the curl command pass using Mongoid?**

Comment: my opinion is that: it's better to use [this gem](https://github.com/mediatainment/simple_token_authentication) instead. and please note: if you want to use it just add `gem 'simple_token_authentication', github: 'mediatainment/simple_token_authentication'` to your gemfile cause without the `github:....` part you will get totally different gem :D

Answer (score -2):

I don't see a solution here, so I'll post what has worked for me...

Try this:

```
\curl http://api.localhost:3000/books -IH "Authorization: 56d1ec82764bfcd0efa15cc44f86a757b758c4a2f39c89303c4eb0b3b1b9e229
```